# Xamarin: How to prevent navigation to another page until web-service responds

Tags: c#, android, multithreading, xamarin, cross-platform

I'm try to call the web-service to retrieve data that will be displayed on the next page. But, the page is trying to display *empty data* before finishing the web-service request.
Can you please help me with this.

//code

```
var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += async (s, e) =>
{                     
    getEmployeepage(mainContact.managerID);                 
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new ManagerDetailsPage(data()));             
};
manager.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
```

//method for retrieving the data

```
public async void getEmployeepage(String searchvalue)
{
    EmployeeDetailsPage employeeDetailsPage = null;
    try
    { 
        var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://..........");
        var response = await client.GetAsync("criterion?empId=" + searchvalue);
        string jsonString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;                   

        //rest of the logic            

    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method should be awaitable. So `public async void getEmployeepage(String searchvalue)` becomes `public async Task getEmployeepage(String searchvalue)`. With this you can await your method like this:

```
await getEmployeepage(mainContact.managerID);
```

It is also a good practice to extend async method names with the Async attribute. Your method name would change to GetEmployeePageAsync. An other good practice is to allways return a Task. Thus makes a method awaitable. The only exception from this pattern are event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `await` your async calls and change your `getEmployeepage` method form `async void` to `async Task`:

```
var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += async (s, e) =>
{                     
    await getEmployeepage(mainContact.managerID);                 
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new ManagerDetailsPage(data()));             
};
manager.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
```

&

```
public async Task getEmployeepage(String searchvalue)
{
    EmployeeDetailsPage employeeDetailsPage = null;
    try
    { 
        var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://..........");
        var response = await client.GetAsync("criterion?empId=" + searchvalue);
        string jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();                   

        //rest of the logic            

    }
}
```